# How could installed programs slow your computer if they're not running?

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, installation, performance

My question is: in what ways could installed programs have an impact on speed or power of a PC **when they're not running any processes**?

I'm not talking viruses or spamware.  Let's assume the following:

I have a standard, non-customized PC with an up-to-date Windows 10 OS, with an SSD drive.  I ensure that the drive is big enough so that the OS and installed software never consumes more than 50% of the total drive.

I install several (20-30?) pieces of up-to-date, mainstream software, that are appropriate to the power and grade of the computer, and then adjust settings to ensure that they do not run at boot or logon.

I have specified an SSD because I know fragmentation on a typical HDD can slow down disc I/O speeds, so assume fragmentation doesn't occur for the purpose of this question.

Some examples of answers for this question could be:

- a program installs a C++ redistributable which gets loaded each time Windows starts and thus has an impact on boot times
- a program can add registry keys which are also loaded at boot
  and each key will have a (minuscule) effect on boot times.

What other ways can programs affect performance when they're not running?